# How to fetch WooCommerce products with 50% discount?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, pages

I want to make a deal page. where there will be different banners showing different deals and discounts.
Now lets say a user clicks on the 50% discount banner he should be redirected to product page where only 50% discounted products are shown.
The one way is to make a category and redirect users to that category but that is not what I want.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How does WooCommece store 'this product is 50% discounted'? You could write a template that includes a WP_Query that searches for that.

Comment: Actually woocommerce stores only prices base price and sale price.Now how can I write query that calculate discount % and show products with that discount only(50 % discount or any % of discount)